# Heygen Talking avatar demo - migration to Next.js getting 400 Bad request on startSession Function

Tags: next.js, video-streaming

I'm trying to run the demo example but on a version of Next.js(I know riski experimental). So far I'm able to obtain the required information in exactly the following order (based on the example and documentation):

1. I upload the image and receive the ID of the new image (I
   successfully received the response or "talk_photo").
2. I open the session with "NewSession" and pass it the parameters of
   the image and quality (I successfully receive the response).
3. I then pass the session response to the client(the first two operations are
   executed on the server-side). From there, as the next
   step, I create the RTCPeerConnection and pass the ice_servers (this
   step is successful).
4. I then create the descriptions, both remote and local first because
   I need them to generate the onicecandidate (they are also generated
   successfully).
5. Once I have the descriptions, I call the StartSession function
   (because according to the documentation, I need to invoke it before
   calling "realtime ice"). When debugging in the browser, I see that I
   successfully pass the parameters session_id and sdp. However, this
   step (Start Session) fails. I get a 400 Bad Request response.
6. I reproduced the same steps in Insomnia with the parameters, and at
   this point, I always get a Bad Request with message "Invalid request json
   body."

Also, to me seems like if I am having issues or the problem is the way I am passing the parameters to the server, based in the [official demo](https://github.com/HeyGen-Official/RealtimeAvatarDemo), seems to be the right way to pass the parameters.(That demo works) but who knows.

Regarding the ice, I also noticed that I successfully pass the candidates and the sessionID, but it never generates the video because, according to the documentation, I need the response from the StartSession function. Could someone provide an idea of what might be happening? Have someone do something similar? It's my first time dealing with realtime video streaming maybe someone can suggest me another approach. Thank you in advance for your help

So my Home page looks like

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Video from '@/components/video';
import { openSession, client } from '../../lib/client';
import { handleICE } from '../../lib/peer';
import { usePeerConnectionContext } from '@/context/peerConnectionContext';
import Wrapper from '@/components/wrapper';
import { loadPicture } from '../../lib/helpers/scripts';


export const getServerSideProps = (async () => {
    try {
      // Dynamically generate photarID
      const photarID = await loadPicture();
  
      if (photarID !== null) {
        // Call to a openSession with photarID
        const data = await openSession('high', photarID);
  
        // Check if  data is undefined
        if (data === undefined) {
          throw new Error("openSession return value is undefined");
        }
  
        // Return data from props
        return {
          props: {
            session: data, 
          },
        };
      } else {
        console.error("Error: photarID is null");
        return {
          props: {
            sessionInfo: null,
          },
        };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error happened trying to get data from server:", error.message);
      return {
        props: {
          sessionInfo: null, 
        },
      };
    }
})

export default function Home({ session }) {

  const { setPeerConnection } = usePeerConnectionContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
  
    const setupPeerConnection = async () => {
      try {
        if (session == null) {
          return;
        }
          // Get data from session
        const { ice_servers: iceServers, sdp: serverSdp, session_id } = session;
          // Create new RTCPeersConnection
        const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers });
          // Just check connection every 3 minutes and try to connect if connection fails
        peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
          console.log( peerConnection.iceConnectionState)
          if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === "disconnected") {
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            setupPeerConnection();
          }
        };
          // Build RTCSessionDescriptions remote and local, needed for candidates
        const remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(serverSdp);
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);

        const localDescription = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(localDescription);
          // Call to StartSession, based on documentation needs to be done before ice call in function handleICE
        await client(session_id, localDescription); // This is the one how throws the 400 error
          // Obtainen candidates and call to StartSession
        peerConnection.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
          if (candidate) {
            handleICE(session_id, candidate);
          }
        };
  
        if (isMounted) {
          setPeerConnection(peerConnection);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error trying to set up peer connection', error);
      }
    };
  
    setupPeerConnection();

  }, [session]);

  return (
    <main>
      <Wrapper>
        {session && <Video></Video>}
        {session == null || session == undefined && <div>Loading...</div>}
        {session == undefined && <div>openSession return value is undefined...possible connection limit reached, try later</div>}
      </Wrapper>

    </main>
  )
}
```

So my Functions to hanlded the sessions:

```
// Connect to the HEYGEN server client // START SESSION function
// This function is the one who fails
export const client = async (session_id, sdp) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HEYGEN_API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({session_id: session_id, sdp: {type: sdp.type, sdp: sdp.sdp}})
  };
  
  fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HEYGEN_SERVER_URL}/v2/realtime/start`, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

/**
* Open a HEYGEN server NEW SESSION function
* @param {quality} props a string posible values 'high', 'low'
*/
export const openSession = async (quality, photarID) => {
  const dimension = {
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
  }
  if( photarID == null){
  const body = {
    quality,
    avatar: {
      avatar_type: "photar",
      photar_id: photarID,
    },
    voice: {
      voice_id: process.env.HEYGEN_VOICE_ID,
    },
    dimension,
  };
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HEYGEN_SERVER_URL}/v2/realtime/new`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Api-Key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HEYGEN_API_KEY,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
  if (response.status === 500) {
    throw new Error("Server error");
  } else if (response.status === 400) {
    const data = await response.json();
    throw new Error(data.error.message);
  } else {
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.data);
    return data.data;
  }
}
}
```